# jQuery datatables evitar ir al top

Tags: html, jquery, css, datatables

Estoy escribiendo debido a un problema que esta surgiendo en navegadores tales como Brave o Chrome pero no en Firefox, pero que tengo que resolver.

Resulta que estoy llenando un `dataTable`, que luego presionando un `button` pasa una fila de un `dataTable` a otro, esto se hace de forma correcta, sin embargo cuando hago clic, automáticamente se posiciona en el top de la página, algo errado que no consigo solucionar.

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class="card-header py-3">
    <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-dark">Estudiantes</h6>
  </div>
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <!-- <th>Correo</th> -->
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Accion</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <!-- <th>Correo</th> -->
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Accion</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
  <!-- <div class="card shadow mb-4"> -->
    <div class="card-header py-3">
      <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-dark">Seccion</h6>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="card-body"> -->
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="dataTable2" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <!-- <th>Correo</th> -->
              <th>Nombre</th>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Accion</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <!-- <th>Correo</th> -->
              <th>Nombre</th>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Accion</th>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
          <tbody>

          </tbody>
        </table>
      <!-- </div> -->
  <!-- </div> -->
</div>
```

```
<script>

 var idUsers = [];
 var unique = 0;
 $arrayHorario = [];

 function return_unique_number(unique){ //funcion que retorna un valor unico siempre
  unique = unique + 1;  //Para la proxima tambien sirve el siguiente link https://api.jqueryui.com/uniqueId/
  return unique;
 }

 function addUser(id, name, lastname, dni, iddataTable){

  lastname = (lastname)?lastname:'';

  if (iddataTable == 1)
  {
   var dataTable = $('#dataTable2').dataTable();

   dni = !(dni)?'No id':dni;
   $('#dataTable2').dataTable().fnAddData([
     (name)+' '+(lastname),
     dni+""+'<input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" value="'+id+'" id="inputValue'+id+'">',
     ""+'<button type="button" class="btn-floating btn-sm btn-outline-danger" id="accionValuedt2'+id+'" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="botton" title="Remover Estudiante"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-minus"></i></button>'
   ]);

  } else
  {
   var dataTable = $('#dataTable').dataTable();
   dni = !(dni)?'No id':dni;
   $('#dataTable').dataTable().fnAddData([
     (name)+' '+(lastname),
     dni+""+'<input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" value="'+id+'" id="inputValue'+id+'">',
     ""+'<button type="button" class="btn-floating btn-sm btn-outline-success" id="accionValuedt2'+id+'" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="botton" title="Agregar a Seccion"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-plus"></i></button>'
   ]);
  }
 }

 function getTableData(){
  data = [];
  $( ".hello" ).remove();

  var table = $('#dataTable2').DataTable();
  var data_rows = table.rows().data();


  for(i = 0; i < data_rows.length; i++){
   var id = String(data_rows[i]);
   id = (id.split('value="')[1]).split('"')[0];
   data.push(id);
   $('<input>').attr({class:"hello", id: id, name: "section[user_ids][]", value: id}).appendTo("form");  
  }

  return data;
 }


 $(document).ready(function () {

  $('#dataTable').DataTable();
  $('#dataTable2').DataTable();

  $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');

  var data = $.getJSON('/admin/students_users_with_not_section',function(data){


   $.each(data, function(idx, elem){

      elem.dni = !(elem.dni)?'No id':elem.dni;

       $('#dataTable').dataTable().fnAddData([
         (elem.name)+' '+(elem.lastname),
         elem.dni+""+'<input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" value="'+elem.id+'" id="inputValue'+elem.id+'">',
         ""+'<button type="button" class="btn-floating btn-sm btn-outline-success" id="accionValuedt1'+elem.id+'" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="botton" title="Agregar a Seccion"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-plus"></i></button>' 
       ]);

     });      
   });


  $('#dataTable2').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
    var table = $('#dataTable2').DataTable();
    var id, name, lastname, dni;
    for (i = 0; i < ((table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data()).length - 1); i++)
    {
      if (i == 0){
        name = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data()[i];
        lastname = '';
      } else if(i == 1){
        dni = (table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data())[i].split("<")[0];
        id = ((table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data())[i].split('value="')[1]).split('"')[0];    
      } 
    }

    table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).remove().draw(false);
    addUser(id, name, lastname, dni, 2);
    idUsers = getTableData();
  }); 



  $('#dataTable').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
    var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable();

    var id, name, lastname, dni;
    for (i = 0; i < ((table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data()).length - 1); i++)
    {
      if (i == 0){
        name = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data()[i];
        lastname = '';
      } else if(i == 1){
        dni = (table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data())[i].split("<")[0];
        id = ((table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data())[i].split('value="')[1]).split('"')[0];    
      } 
    }

    //table.row( this ).delete();
    table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).remove().draw(false);
    addUser(id, name, lastname, dni, 1);
    idUsers = getTableData();
  }); 

 });

</script>
```

Lo que hace ahora mismo es llenar desde un JSON una primera tabla de id `dataTable` en el cual está en cada ultima columna un botón el cual elimina la fila de esa tabla y lo añade a la tabla de id `dataTable2` que está también, todo esto lo hace de manera correcta según los datos que deseo y viceversa, sin embargo cada vez que presiono el botón en navegadores como Chrome o Brave, por mencionar algunos, la página se posiciona en el top, algo que busco evitar y dejar la página posicionada donde estoy.

Comment: Saludos intentalo agregandolo asi: "href="javascript:void(0);"...es decir cierralo con el punto y coma ";"..

Comment: Ya los agregué, pero sigue ocurriendo lo mismo. Va hacia el top de la pagina.

Comment: AL final detecté el problema, y era el fontawesome, el cual realiza la acción de ir al top de la página. Los eliminé por el momento. Si alguna persona sabe como incluir estos iconos sin que realice esta función, estaré pendiente al igual si consigo darle solución usando los iconos, colocaré la misma.

Comment: Saludos, me acabo de percatar que tienes "<button...."...cuando deberia ser...<a href="javascript:void(0);"........

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, efectivamente, eso lo cambié, más sin embargo debido a los iconos es que surge el incoveniente.